# Copy dynamic range and paste dynamic range with duplicate value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy and paste dynamic range. Especially paste with duplicate value for each source of copy range. Here is code I created from recording a macro:

```
Sub copyRange()
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("L2:S7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("L8:S13").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("A4").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("L14:S19").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("A5").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=3
Range("L20:S25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

this is screenshot output i want:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Prasar Khode for correction my queston

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub CopyPasteData()
Dim lRw As Long, lRw_2 As Long, x As Long, rActive As Range

Set rActive = ActiveCell
lRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("K2:R" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

For i = 2 To lRw
    x = x + 1
    Range("A" & i & ":H" & i).Copy
    lRw_2 = Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    With Range("K" & lRw_2).Resize(6)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .Offset(, -1).Value = x
    End With
Next i

Application.CutCopyMode = False
rActive.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks Sixthense it's working but when I run sub CopyPasteData once again or two time it's repeat copy data to range target after all source copy range. I want just one time only, not repeating when run that sub. Many Thank's for you help.

Comment: Added Range("K2:R" & Rows.Count).ClearContents line in the above code to clear the old entries.